# How to prove that every category can be construct from graphs by relations and generators

Tags: category-theory

Let $U: Cat \to Graph$ be the forgetful functor and $L: Graph \to Cat$ the associated functor that returns the free category from a graph. Let $C$ be a category, I have to construct a graph $G_C$ a congruence relation $R$ in $L(G_C)$ and a category isomorphism:

$$L(G_C)/R \cong C.$$

My first thought was to take $G_C$ to be $U(C)$. But, when I make $LU(C)$, to remember the path, I realized that if we already have a composite arrow in $C$:

$$h = gf$$

then $LU(C)$ will find another arrow say $h'$ not necessarily equal to $h$ such tat $h'= gf$. So I thought we could just take $G_C$ to be $U(C)$ less the composite arrows. But this can't be right, since I wouldn't use the relation for nothing (I could also to think in a appropriate relation to get rid of the excessive arrows, but I think I am over-complicating it).

Comment: Have you tried constructing $R$ so that $h'$ and $h$ are equivalent modulo $R$?

Comment: Yes, I started the exercise like this. But then I thought: why not just take this $G_C$ to be just the graph less the composites and the identities? But then, i didn't even need to to construct this relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to other constructions, like showing every group is a quotient of a free group (in fact, this is a special case of what we’re showing).

The graph in question is indeed $U(C)$. Let $G = U(C)$.

Let $C’ = L(G)$. Then consider the graph morphism $\eta_{G} : G \to U(C’)$.

The $R$ in question is precisely the equivalence relation generated by the equations $\eta_G(f) \circ \eta_G(g) = \eta_G(f \circ g)$ and $\eta_G(1_A) = 1_{\eta_G(a)}$ for all composable morphisms $f, g$ and all objects $A$ in $C$.

With such an $R$, we can show that the functor $\epsilon_C : C’ \to C$ factors through $C’/R \to C$. We can then explicitly construct the inverse of this functor to show it is an isomorphism of categories.